# Tera Term Scripting, need help developing a macro

Tags: scripting, macros

I am using a Tera Term over a serial port to do some testing on a board. Recently I found out I can do some scripting in Tera Term so I have been doing research to help automate and make testing a little easier.

I know Tera Term has a site that lists example macros as well as a command list but I guess what I need is someone with experience scripting in Tera Term.

Tera Term uses a sort of Basic language called Tera Term Language (TTL) but I found it hard from the site to actually identify which commands I needed to use.

Tera Term site: http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/ < -- **Note: Site is in Japanese but I always have it auto translated...**

I am trying to develop a script to play a set of tracks using a "play x" command, where x is the track index. Ideally the track will play for ~3 seconds and then increment up to the next track. I have a very crude outline algorithm that I should describe it.

Algorithm:

> ```
> ;start
>
> ;input to take in number of track to test n tracks
> ;input is stored in "n"
> i=0
>
> do while i < (n+1)
>
> ;play track i for 3 seconds
>
> i++
>
> end  while
>
> ;stop
> ```

If anyone has any insights or experience with Tera Term I would be very appreciative.

**If anything right now I need to figure out how to take an inputbox input and store it to a variable.** I can probably figure out the rest...

Comment: It is the tool I was told to use for the project, I dunno about 13 years, the latest version was dated earlier this year...

If you know of a similar tool that works better I am open to it...

Comment: Ah, I see you updated with a link.  I thought you were talking about this tool.  http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA002416/teraterm.html

Comment: My bad, I meant to add a link but forgot in the original post (obviously), I updated it again to include a bolded request, which should make the question a little more simpler...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I did some digging and found a moderately active forum:
**[link deleted, forum no longer active, malware threat]**

It is there that I found a nice thread called: ***TeraTerm Macro Language for dummies...***
**[link deleted, forum no longer active, malware threat]**

That, and the command list on the actual TeraTerm project site is where I have been troubleshooting and solving 90% of my issues.

To take in a user defined input you use the "inputbox" command, which follows the format:

> **inputbox 'message' 'title' [default]**

(not entirely sure what default is supposed to be doing)

E.G.

> **inputbox 'Please type input' 'Input'**

a dialog box will appear and prompt a response. This input is sent to a default variable **inputstr**

I have gotten this variable to work in some cases but I think the problem is that the variable is technically a string type so I can't do traditional loops. I need to figure out a way to use the str2int command to do an expression.

I think that answers my own immediate question as well as provide some reference for others...

Thanks

Comment: In case anyone else tries to follow the link: the forum link appears to no longer work.